# dev-c++ Having troubles with somekind of a question mark

Tags: dev-c++

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCmow.png)

[This is what I get in return... Now I'm wondering where is that "?" coming from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytpOw.png)

Comment: Past your code and response here. Links may not work forever and there are people searching questions after few years sometime. Not to mention that's very hard to copy-paste from jpg...

Answer (score 0):

None of your 'polje' variables are initialized. This means that they contain more or less random junk. You need to initialize them all, for instance

```
char polje1 = 'a';
```